# Elastic Fleet server API Deployment

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create fully automated script for SIEM deployment. There is one issue. I am not able to install fleet server. I want it to be fully automated no UI interaction. So first i need to create policy using API which i was able to do. Then I need to add fleet server integration to this policy and enroll fleet server using agent package and policy token. I just cannot add fleet to my policy using API. Can someone please provide me any tips for that. This is code responsible for creation of a policy:

```
fleet_policy_id=$(curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://10.*.*.*:5601/api/fleet/agent_policies?sys_monitoring=true' \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic *********************** \
  --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'kbn-xsrf: xxx' \
  --data '{
  "name": "Agent policy 11",
  "description": "",
  "namespace": "default",
  "monitoring_enabled": [
    "logs",
    "metrics"
  ]
}' --insecure | jq -r '.item.id')

echo $fleet_policy_id

response=$(curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://10.*.*.*:5601/api/fleet/package_policies' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic **************************** \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'kbn-xsrf: xx' \
  --data '{
  "name": "Fleet",
  "policy_id": "$fleet_policy_id",
  "package": {
    "name": "fleet_server",
    "version": "1.2.0"
  }

}' --insecure)

echo $response
```

I get the policy created in fleet server but cannot assign fleet integration to it:
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i got this. To anyone wondering. You have to add

"has_fleet_server: true" to the first request:

```
    fleet_policy_id=$(curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://10.*.*.*:5601/api/fleet/agent_policies?sys_monitoring=true' \
  --header 'Accept: */*' \
  --header 'Authorization: Basic **************************' \
  --header 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --header 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'kbn-xsrf: xxx' \
  --data '{
  "name": "Agent policy 12",
  "description": "",
  "namespace": "default",
  "monitoring_enabled": [
    "logs",
    "metrics"
  ],
  "has_fleet_server": "true"
}' --insecure | jq -r '.item.id')
```